# C++ two way association memory management strategy

Tags: c++, memory-management

I've implemented a heap using two classes called IndexedHeap and HeapEntry. I have some corrupt memory access causing segfaults and I believe I know where/why, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Here's how I've designed the classes so far:

```
class IndexedHeap
{
private:
    std::vector<HeapEntry*> heap; // the entries held by this heap
public:
    ...
};

class HeapEntry
{
private:
    int index;
    size_t priority;
    unsigned long long key;
    IndexedHeap* myHeap; // reference to heap where this entry resides
public:
    HeapEntry(unsigned long long key, size_t priority, IndexedHeap* myHeap)
        : key(key), priority(priority), index(-1), myHeap(myHeap)
    {}
};
```

Both the heap and its entries need to refer to each other. As you can see I've decided to use a raw pointer to an IndexedHeap in HeapEntry. This is where I think I went wrong, but I'm not sure.

Throughout program execution, new heap entries are created as part of **one heap**.  Entries are also removed from this heap and destroyed. Perhaps when one heap entry is destroyed, the heap it points to gets corrupted. That would explain my memory issues, because the next time a heap entry tries to access its heap, it accesses memory that has been released.

Unfortunately I'm not convinced of that. I haven't implemented a destructor for HeapEntry. The default destructor just calls destructors for all instance variables of a class right? So wouldn't the pointer to myHeap get destroyed, while the heap object itself survives?

So, what is the correct way of designing this kind of relationship, and can my memory issues be explained from the code I've posted? Thanks, and please let me know if you'd like to see more code or more details.

Code that creates and destroys entries on the heap:

```
HeapEntry* IndexedHeap::insert(unsigned long long key)
{
    HeapEntry* entry = new HeapEntry(key, 1, this);
    heap.push_back(entry);
    int index = heapifyUp(heap.size() - 1);
    heap[index]->setIndex(index);
    return entry;
}

void IndexedHeap::deleteAtIndex(int pos)
{
    if (pos >= 0 && pos < heap.size())
    {
        // Copy heap.back() into the position of target, thus overwriting it
        *heap[pos] = *heap.back();

        // Fix the index field for the just copied element
        heap[pos]->setIndex(pos);

        // We've removed the target by overwriting it with heap.back()
        // Now get rid the extra copy of heap.back()
        // Release the mem, then pop back to get rid of the pointer
        delete heap.back();
        heap.pop_back();

        // Heapify from the position we just messed with
        // use heapifyDown because back() always has a lower priority than the element we are removing
        heapifyDown(pos);
    }
}
```

Comment: How does a HeapEntry get allocated, and how is it supposed to get freed? How do you make sure noone has a danling pointer to the already freed HeapEntry? Using a plain old pointer in an STL-container class is a sure ticket to memory corruption, if the STL-container is involved in freeing your pointer. You should go & read about smart pointers.

Comment: Well, why aren't you using the priority queue from STL, or using a multimap as a priority queue? Its a better solution than writing your own.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with smart pointers, so I will definitely read on them and try to see where they can help. I'll also edit the question now to include the code that creates and destroys the heap entries.

Comment: Why are you using dynamic memory allocation?

Comment: @Jefffrey I also have a hash table in my program, and each hash table entry corresponds to one of these heap entries, so I store a HeapEntry* there. I'm taking a look to see if perhaps I can get by with a reference instead. Thanks for asking that important question.

Comment: @yan, I still don't see any reasons to use dynamic memory. But hey, if you are happy with it, go on. Just make sure it's exception safe, follows the rule of 3 (now 5) and doesn't leak any memory.

Answer (score 1):

Well, firstly, why arent you using the priority queue from STL, or using a multimap as a priority queue? Its a better solution than writing your own.

Next, the code structure:  `std::vector<HeapEntry*> heap;` is notorious for leaking memory, with people not deleteing the memory pointed to, while and for causing serious memory faults when people try to delete the pointed memory and get that deletion wrong.

The `"IndexedHeap* myHeap;"` is most likely not your problem. References to things you dont own can be an issue if someone deletes those objects, but chances are you have stopped using th entries by then. Btw, since its a reference, you should consider making it a reference (which is then bound during ctr and never changed) - but that wouold alter the safety of the code in anyway. As youbelieve, the dtr for a pointer does nothing to the target.

Can you run valgrind? it solve things like this very quickly. Else:

Try not deleting any Entries, and see if that stops your faults, if so its telling.

You could also try tracking the pointers you new and delete, either by prints, or by a global set/map object. This can be handy to find these things.

Comment: I'm building my own because it has some extra functionality. Namely, to be able to delete an entry from the middle of the heap, re-heapify, and maintain the heap ordering. I'm not aware of an existing implementation of such a heap. I'm on windows using gcc with mingw, so valgrind isn't an option. I'll try some of your debugging tips for now.

Comment: Ok, I suspect a multimap could support much of give you want you want there. It defintely allows for deletion (which I agree the the priority queue type doesnt). Though perhaps identifying, passing around, referencing the entries can be a little tricky.

Comment: One more suggestion: you could write a `validate()` function which goes through the whole tree and checks if invariant statements are still true (back and forth pointers are correct, index numbers are correct, etc). If the result is that the tree gets into an invalid state, you can call this validating function from a few places in your code to see where the state gets corrupted.